# неккоректная валидация формы в гет запросе

Tags: java, post, get, spring-boot

В SpringBoot проекте делаю валидацию формы, на get запрос происходит проверка данных и сразу пишется ошибка.

Контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("registration")
public class RegistrationController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("results").setViewName("results");
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String init(RegistrationForm registrationForm) {
    System.out.println("get");
    return "form";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkRegistratioInfo(@Valid RegistrationForm registrationForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println("post");
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }
    return "redirect:results";
}
```

form, есть гетеры, сетеры.

```
 public class RegistrationForm {
@NotNull(message = "Please enter your login.")
@Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Your login must between 3 and 20 characters")
private String login;


@NotNull(message = "Please enter your password.")
@Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "Your password must between 5 and 20 characters")
private String password;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter your email first name.")
@Size(min = 4, max = 20, message = "Your first name must between 4 and 20 characters")
private String first_name;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter your email last name.")
@Size(min = 4, max = 20, message = "Your last name must between 4 and 20 characters")
private String last_name;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter your email middle name.")
@Size(min = 4, max = 20, message = "Your middle name must between 4 and 20 characters")
private String middle_name;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter your information about yourself")
@Size(min = 20, message = "Your information about yourself must be min 20 characters")
private String your_info;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter your mobile phone.")
private Integer mobile_phone;

private Integer home_phone;

@Size(min = 10, message = "Your address must be min 10 characters")
private String address;

@Email
private String email;
```

html страница

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<form action="#" th:th:action="@{registration}" th:object="${registrationForm}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <tr class="tg">
            <th colspan="2"><h4>Регистрация</h4></th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Login:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{login}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('login')}" th:errors="*{login}">Name Error</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Пароль:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{password}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Имя:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{first_name}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('first_name')}" th:errors="*{first_name}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Фамилия:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{last_name}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('last_name')}" th:errors="*{last_name}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Отчество:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{middle_name}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('middle_name')}" th:errors="*{middle_name}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Информация о Вас:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{your_info}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('your_info')}" th:errors="*{your_info}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Мобильный телефон:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{mobile_phone}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mobile_phone')}" th:errors="*{mobile_phone}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Домашний телефон:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{home_phone}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('home_phone')}" th:errors="*{home_phone}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Адрес:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{address}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}" th:errors="*{address}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" th:field="*{email}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Регистрация"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите что надо изменить что б на гет запрос было обычное отображение страницы, на пост проходила проверка данных?
[ссылка на проект](https://github.com/MaximDzhezhelo/PhoneBook.git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Spring MVC сконфигурирован на использование JSP страниц в качестве View, но сами jsp написаны частично в синтаксисе шаблонов Thymeleaf. Для решения проблемы есть два варианта:
**Вариант 1:**
Переписать описанное в шаблоне Thymeleaf на JSP с использованием тегов, предоставляемых Spring MVC, так (часть формы пропущенна):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@include file="head.jsp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="box">
            <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="registrationForm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <tr class="tg">
                        <th colspan="2"><h4>Регистрация</h4></th>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Login:</td>
                        <td><form:input path="login" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="login" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Пароль:</td>
                        <td><form:input path="password" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
                            value="Регистрация"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

В классе `RegistrationController` нужно изменить метод `init` так:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String init(ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.put("registrationForm", new RegistrationForm());
    return "Register";
}
```

**Вариант 2:**
Использовать Thymeleaf в качестве View в Spring MVC.
Для этого понадобится убрать из кофигурации `AppConfig` метод `viewResolver` и полностью привести существующие страницы к формату Thymeleaf. Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/).

*Небольшой комментарий к обработке метода POST*
При обработке метода POST следует придерживаться парадигмы [Post/Redirect/Get](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), это позволит избежать проблем с повторной отправкой формы (например если пользователь после успешного сохранения обновит страницу в браузере). Для этого метод `RegistrationController#checkRegistratioInfo` следует переписать так:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkRegistratioInfo(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("registrationForm") RegistrationForm registrationForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "Register";
    }

    return "redirect:welcome";
}
```

а в `HomeController` добавить метод

```
@RequestMapping(path="welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    return "Welcome";
}
```